# Switching a's and b's in a String C++ [Code Wars Problem]

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

std::string switcheroo(const std::string &s) {
  string myString = s;
  
  int i = 0;
  int j = s.length();
  
  if(s[i] != 'a' || s[i] != 'b') i++;
  if(s[j] != 'a' || s[j] != 'b') j--;
  else
  {
    swap(myString[i],myString[j]);
  }
  return myString;
}
```

Here is the link for the Code Kata problem in code wars https://www.codewars.com/kata/57f759bb664021a30300007d/train/cpp

It wants me to switch instances of a's and b's and I have done this problem before with switching vowels and so the same algorithm should work. What am I doing wrong with my code?

Comment: that `if-if-else` construct looks fishy and most likely is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Your condition is always true, try to think about why is that.

Comment: `Assert::That(switcheroo("bbbb"), Equals("aaaa"));`: you don't have to swap **position**, just transform letter one by one.

Comment: you are missing a loop...

Comment: `s[i] != 'a' || s[i] != 'b'` is always true, you're indexing outside the string, and you're at most swapping two characters of the string. Don't you think you need a loop somewhere?

Comment: You should try [rubber duck debuggine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Start at the first line, step line by line through the code and describe what each line does.

Comment: @jabaa Thank you for that method, I heard that explaining your solution to a peer who knows a little about programming helps. Didn't know you could use it with an inanimate object haha.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah I just saw that I didn't even take a second look at it until now.

Comment: Regarding `(s[i] != 'a' || s[i] != 'b')`, I like to apply DeMorgan's Law in my head to make sure it still makes sense (sometimes changing negative logic to positive logic or vice versa helps), so then it becomes `!(s[i] == 'a' && s[i] == 'b')`, which points out the flawed logic of when can `s[i]` equal `'a'` and `'b'` at the same time?

Comment: @franji1 Ah I got it! Thanks a lot. I will definitely use this when I am debugging my code and creating it.

Comment: I added a second version of the function to my answer that uses `std::transform`, just so you could see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version of the function that passes all tests.

Because the parameter `s` is passed in as a reference to const, we can't make changes to it directly. So, we declare a new string, `tmp`, and build it letter by letter. The key is looping through `s` so that we can examine each letter. If it's `'a'`, be add a `'b'` to `tmp`. If it's a `'b'`, we add `'a'` to `tmp`. And if it's neither, we just add that letter as-is. By the time the loop finishes, we've looked at every letter in `s` and built `tmp` with the `'a'`s and `'b'`s swapped. So we return `tmp`.

```cpp
std::string switcheroo(const std::string &s) {
  std::string tmp;
  for (const auto& i : s) {
    if (i == 'a') {
      tmp.push_back('b');
    } else if (i == 'b') {
      tmp.push_back('a');
    } else {
      tmp.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  
  return tmp;
}
```

From your comment, here's another version that passes all tests and uses `std::transform()`.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string switcheroo(const std::string &s) {
  std::string tmp;
  
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp), 
                [](const auto& i) {
                  if (i == 'a') { return 'b'; }
                  if (i == 'b') { return 'a'; }
                  return i;
                });
  return tmp;
}
```

Without running a profiler, I can't say whether this code faster, but the way that the lambda is built makes me think it might have a slight performance edge. That's because consecutive `if` statements can be faster than a large `if/else` block. You likely wouldn't see a large difference unless the string being processed was massive.

Comment: Ah got it! Is this the most effective way though? What's the fastest possible solution? Can't we use a function where it transforms every occurrence of a to b and vice versa like maybe using the transform function?

Comment: Because `s` is taken as a reference to const, it cannot be altered. While you could probably do something with fewer lines of code using something from the Standard Library, the actual runtime would be similar. There's no way to do this without examining each character of `s`, so you're always going to end up with O(n) runtime.

Comment: Sheesh man do you just remember lamda functions at the top of your head or do you have to look it up usually cause the code is kind of confusing when you use [] (const auto &i ). Its clean though.