# Switching a's and b's in a String Java 7KYU Kata Codewars

Tags: java

```
Given a string made up of letters a, b, and/or c, switch the position of letters a and b (change a to b and vice versa). Leave any incidence of c untouched.

Example:

'acb' --> 'bca'
'aabacbaa' --> 'bbabcabb'
```

My Code ->

```
        public class Switch {
        public static String switcheroo(String x) {
        
            char[] arr = x.toCharArray();
         for (int i=0;i<(x.length()-1);i++){
            if(arr[i]=='a'){
              arr[i]='b';
            }
            else if(arr[i]=='b'){
              arr[i]='a';
            }
          }
        x = String.valueOf(arr);
        
        return x;
      }
    }
```

Im getting an error

`expected:<aaabcccbaa[a]> but was:<aaabcccbaa[b]>`

I am Unable to figure out this please help.
Link to question - https://www.codewars.com/kata/57f759bb664021a30300007d/train/java

Comment: is marked as duplicate, you can find the solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022118/switching-as-and-bs-in-a-string-c-code-wars-problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching a's and b's in a String C++ \[Code Wars Problem\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67022118/switching-as-and-bs-in-a-string-c-code-wars-problem)

Comment: You are evaluating everything except for the last character in the array-converted string with your `for` function with  `(int i=0;i<(x.length()-1);i++){`. Use `x.length()` rather than `(x.length()-1)` to make your switcheroo evaluate every character in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist your loop, when iterating starting at zero only check less than length `i < x.lenth()`. The "length minus one" is needed when starting with one eg: `for (int i = 1; i < (x.length() - 1); i++) ...`. Since you did both the last char is never iterated over and cannot be changed by the code inside your loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {
    if (arr[i] == 'a') {
        arr[i] = 'b';
    }
    else if (arr[i] == 'b') {
        arr[i] = 'a';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary substitution with replacements:

```java
return x.replace('a', '_').replace('b', 'a').replace('_', 'b');
```

this should work well.

Comment: It will work, but  only if the string doesn't contain any `_` characters beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem comes from your index, your are looping on your array but your code stops at `i < (x.length -1)`. To fix it, you only have to remove the minus one part : `i < x.length` or `i <= (x.length - 1)`

Answer (score -1):

you can use the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::string switcheroo(const std::string &s) {
  std::string tmp;
  
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(tmp), 
                [](const auto& i) {
                  if (i == 'a') { return 'b'; }
                  if (i == 'b') { return 'a'; }
                  return i;
                });
  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: This is c++, not java.